# PL/SQL Error ORA-01403 no data found

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I'm recieving the ORA-01403 no data found error when trying to insert in a table after creating the following trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER unic_disc
BEFORE insert ON disciplina
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    CURSOR cursor_professor IS 
    SELECT matricula_professor
    FROM disciplina;
    temp_prof disciplina.matricula_professor%type;
BEGIN
    OPEN cursor_professor;
    FETCH cursor_professor INTO temp_prof;
    CLOSE cursor_professor;
END;
/
```

(the variables are in portugues, but their name does not interfere in the logic.)
the table creation,

```
CREATE TABLE disciplina (
    codigo_disciplina NUMBER,
    ementa VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    conteudo_programatico VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
    matricula_professor NUMBER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT disciplina_pk PRIMARY KEY (codigo_disciplina),
    CONSTRAINT disciplina_matricula_prof_fk FOREIGN KEY (matricula_professor)         REFERENCES professor (matricula_professor)
);
```

My insert query:

```
INSERT INTO disciplina (codigo_disciplina,ementa,conteudo_programatico,matricula_professor) VALUES (7,'E6', 'C6',7777);
```

EDIT: I think the error is because I am selecting from the same table I'm editing.

Comment: are there any other  triggers on the table?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use the cursor this way and not iterate over it?

Comment: There are other triggers and the actual trigger I'm using is more complicated, I have simplified it for the purpose of finding the error. In the actual trigger, I iterate over the cursor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just needed to add PRAGMA_AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION after the DECLARE AND IT WORKED. I couldn't find it on my own, a friend told me.

Comment: Where did you add it?

Comment: Right after "DECLARE"

Comment: If you edit your answer to include that information I can remove my downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are using a trigger (before insert) initially the table does not have any data and

the trigger is fired before insert when you are trying to insert data in the table, it

returns you with no records found . if you specify what is your requirement exactly i will

try to help you with the  code .

Comment: This trigger is added after the tables have been populated to some degree. The requirement is "create a trigger that does not allow inserting a discipline whose professor is already vinculated to another discipline".